# Gstreamer frames handlem

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, video-processing

I'm on my project about rtsp streams, merging and stuff and one of things I need to do is to pass frames from rtsp stream to a handler or buffer or something so another person could process it with f.e. OpenCV.
how could I do it with gstreamer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GStreamer already has [opencv based plugins](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/ext/opencv) (. So the best way is to write a similar plugin that applys your opencv code. There are elements called appsrc and appsink to source data from ann app or receive data by an app, but there is not appfilter element. One could use a pad-probe for it, but it is not a good approach.